# Internal style not overriding external style sheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm stuck on this even though it is very simple.

I'm have a custom css file. In this I have added this piece of code:

```
input[type=text] {
   margin-top:5px;
   width:370px;
}
```

I have one page where I want to override this but when I try to with the following, the width of the text input does not change.

```
input[type=text] {
   width:100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue anywhere we could see?

Comment: are you loading your override *AFTER* the bootstrap css? Or before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<input type=text style="width:100px;" />` That seems to work for me when using bootstrap .

Comment: It's a input that appears in my DataTable so I can't do that

Comment: Can't you add some javascript so that it adds it when the page has completed loading ? `$("input").css("width","100px");`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CSS classes here, not to mention its better practise to use percentages rather than finite pixel values.

In any case, avoid inline CSS because thats bad practice.

CSS:

```
#narrow_input {
    width:100px;
}
```

html:

```
<input type=text class="narrow_input" />
```

That way when you decide to make the narrow input red as well, you can just add `color:red;` to the stylesheet.